# iOS Developement: App Crashes on Reopen

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app is almost finish but when i am testing it, on first use everything is working well and smooth. But, after closing it from the home button and reopen it when i click my back it;s crashing.

in my back button i only have this code:

```
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
        [view2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self view3];
```

what could be the problem??

Comment: What does the back button do?  Is it the back button you get from a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: no, it is a custom UIButton. It just removes 2 UIImageView then call a method.

Comment: is this the entire code in your back button was pressed method?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing views from superview when you push the back button.

also what do you think will happen by saying

[self view3]; ?

I would suggest if you've added views in the viewDidLoad method

that you should remove them using the viewdidUnload method and not in the back button method. As if you try an remove a view that has already been release, your app will crash.

If you're attempting something different then you need to show more code.